# Getting limits to look right

Tags: math-mode

How do you get the `\delta\rightarrow 0` underneath the line underneath the limit.

This is what I have so far

```
\underline{\lim\limits}_{\delta \rightarrow 0}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  $\lim\limits_{\overline{δ\rightarrow 0}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not my best choice, actually.

Answer (score 9):

You have a dedicated command for that: `\varliminf`. There also exists a `\varlimsup` command. Likewise, in another domain of maths, we have `\varinjlim` and `\varprojlim` commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    & \varliminf_{δ \to 0} &\qquad &\varinjlim_{i ∈ I}E_i \\
    & \varlimsup_{δ \to 0} & & \varprojlim_{i ∈ I}E_i
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually `amsmath` is sufficient.

Comment: @egreg: I know that; `mathtools` should be systematically loaded, in my opinion, and my predefined templates load it.