# Lower and Upper Limits

Tags: math-operators

I am writing a document about limits of functions. I need to use notation for the lower limit, which I have as the normal limit sign but with 'lim' underlined. I need the same for the upper limit with 'lim' overlined.

For the overlined I have tried to use

```
\overline{\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}}
```

but that overlines all of it, I just want it over the 'lim' part.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: it already exists in the `amsmath` package under the name of `\varliminf`. See my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205113/getting-limits-to-look-right) for this symbol and a few others in the same style. (lim sup, direct and inverse limits).

Comment: @Bernard: Of course!! (;-)  So, this question should probably be marked as a duplicate, shouldn’t it?

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti: It's also my opinion.

Comment: @Bernard: Done.  But probably, you have got a gold badge that allows you to bypass the vote.

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti: I don't how to do that. I simply voted to close (which I rarely do).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a notation I recognise, but

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*\lowlim{\underline{lim}}
\DeclareMathOperator*\uplim{\overline{lim}}

\begin{document}

\[
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \rightarrow
\lowlim_{x \to 0^{+}} \rightarrow
\uplim_{x \to 0^{+}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. It's not notation I particularly like, but I couldn't think of a better one.

Comment: It's not my notation. I am reading a book by Kenneth Falconer.

Comment: @JSharpee Sorry! I misunderstood your comment, I deleted earlier comment (I still don't like the notation much though:-)

Comment: Aha, that's ok. I don't either. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JSharpee: Speaking of better notations, of course you know that LaTeX has `\liminf` and `\limsup`, which yield “lim inf” and “lim sup”, respectively, don’t you?

Comment: I didn't. That is annoying ¬.¬ Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, this works:

```
$\overline{\lim}_{x \to 0^{+}}$
```

And it looks like this:

[image: Bar over lim]

Comment: that loses the mathop classification, so gets different spacing and the limit comes in subscript position not underneath as it does for `\lim`

Comment: Huh. That is weird and disturbing that it works. I will use the answer above if that's ok. Thanks though.